# Can you appending a row of different size to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update some data in an excel sheet from a csv. After loading the data, I am trying to see if an ID exists and if it does not, append it to the dataframe, example:

df:

```
  0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
```

df2:

```
  0 1 2
0 5 6 7
1 2 3 4
```

Result:

```
  0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 NaN
```

I have tried just appending the row df.append(df2). I'm sure an easy work around is to add a value in to replace the NaN to be 0, but I am dealing with a larger scale data set so I would need to find a better way if any.

ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.

Comment: dataframes, the indexes are there for reference, the column I'm trying to match on is column 1, then append to the dataframe

Comment: Have you tried: `pd.concat([df1, df2])` which'll put `NaN` by default.

Comment: Just tried it, it does work! Thank you! I was so dead set on using append, I didn't even look at concat.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I should be using concat to get produce the desired results.